# angularjs modal cancel not functioning

Tags: angularjs

I have created a modal on click of add new button, in the modal i have save and close buttons, i have function written i my controller to close  click , so that modal closes on click, but i am having issues with these. 
the code is provided below

view code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clickAddComment()">Add new</button>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
               <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Comments Section</h3>
               </div>     
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                    <form>
                    <label for="text">Name</label><br />
                    <input type="text class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" /> <br />
                                 <label for="text">Author</label><br />
                    <input type="text class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Name" /><br />
                                 <label for="text">Date</label><br />
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" style="width:155px;" id="currdate" /> <br />
                                <label for="text">Comments</label><br />
                   <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

                    </form>  
                   </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="canc()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
</script>
```

and in controller i have

```
   $scope.clickAddComment = function() {
        modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'someController'
        });
    }

$scope.canc = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('canc');
  };
```

Comment: Could you post a plunkr ?

Answer (score 0):

```
just added modalInstance to canc function instead of $uibModalInstance as i am targetting the same modal 
 $scope.clickAddComment = function() {
        modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'someController'
        });
    }
$scope.canc = function () {
        modalInstance.dismiss('canc');
    };
```